# Krajee Bootstrap File Input, ajax, codeigniter, upload trigger file with another data in one form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Basically, I want my user to fill some input form and upload a lot image file in one form. Here is the little piece of the code.

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('', array('id' => 'upload', 'enctype' => "multipart/form-data")); ?>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-md-4">
     <label for="last5">Last 5 Test</label>
     <input type="text" name="last5" id="last5" class="form-control" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-md-4">
     <label for="cert5">Certified By</label>
     <input type="text" name="cert5" id="cert5" class="form-control"  />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-md-2">
     <label for="driver">Driver</label>
     <input type="text" name="driver" id="driver" class="form-control"  />
  </div>

  /*This is for upload file*/
  <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
     <label for="file">Upload Foto</label>
     <input name="file[]" id="file" type="file" multiple >    
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6 ">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Update & Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Reset</button>
  </div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

I use php codeigniter on side server. Now, to submit those data, I use AJAX twice, first, I want make sure the common input is success then upload those file on next.

So, I declare those file input :

```
$("#file").fileinput({
    dropZoneEnabled : false,
    showUpload : false,
    uploadUrl: "http://localhost/depo/", // Please, triggered upload
    uploadAsync: false,
    maxFileCount: 10
});
```

And here is the AJAX :

```
$(document).on('submit', '#upload', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#no_surat').prop("disabled", false);

        var form = $('#upload');
        var inputFile = $('input#file');
        var filesToUpload = inputFile[0].files;

        // make sure there is file(s) to upload
        if (filesToUpload.length > 0) {
            // provide the form data that would be sent to sever through ajax
            var formData = new FormData();

            for (var i = 0; i < filesToUpload.length; i++) {
                var file = filesToUpload[i];
                formData.append("file[]", file, file.name);
            }

            $.ajax({ //Upload common input
                url: "<?php echo base_url('surveyor/c_surveyor_inspection/update_by_inspection_surveyor_2'); ?>",
                type: "POST",
                data: form.serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.Status === 1) {
                        $.ajax({ //Then upload the foto
                            url: "<?php echo base_url('surveyor/c_surveyor/add_file_image/'); ?>/" + response.Nama_file + '/' + response.No_surat,
                            type: 'post',
                            data: formData,
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            success: function (obj) {
                                $('#no_surat').prop("disabled", true);
                                console.log("The photos is successfully upload");
                            }, fail: function () {
                                console.log('Error');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('#file').after('<div class="callout callout-danger lead" id="div_error"><p id="pesan_error"></p></div>');
            $('#div_error').fadeIn("fast");
            $('#pesan_error').html("Harap sertakan foto...");
            $('#div_error').fadeOut(7000);
        }
        return false;
    });
```

This is the code to handling image upload:

```
public function add_file_image() {
    $last = $this->uri->total_segments();
    $id = $this->uri->segment($last);

    echo urldecode($this->uri->segment($last));

    $pathToUpload = "D:\Foto\ " . $this->uri->segment(4, 0) . '-' . $this->uri->segment(5, 0);
    if (!is_dir($pathToUpload)) {
        mkdir($pathToUpload, 0755, true);
        mkdir($pathToUpload . '\thumbs', 0755, true);
    }
    $dir_exist = true; // flag for checking the directory exist or not

    if (!is_dir($pathToUpload)) {
        mkdir($pathToUpload, 0755, true);
        mkdir($pathToUpload . '\thumbs', 0755, true);
        $dir_exist = false; // dir not exist
    }

    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $config['upload_path'] = $pathToUpload;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['file_name'] = $id;
        $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
        //$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        $this->load->library('upload');

        $files = $_FILES;
        $number_of_files = count($_FILES['file']['name']);

        $errors = 0;
        $upload_array = array();

        // codeigniter upload just support one fileto upload. so we need a litte trick
        for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files; $i++) {
            $_FILES['file']['name'] = $files['file']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['type'] = $files['file']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $files['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['error'] = $files['file']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['size'] = $files['file']['size'][$i];
            // we have to initialize before upload

            $config['file_name'] = $this->uri->segment(4, 0) . '-' . $this->uri->segment(5, 0) . '-' . $i;
            // UPLOAD EKSEKUSI
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload("file")) {
                $errors++;
                echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            } else {
                $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                print_r($upload_data);
                $new_upload = array(
                    "NO_INSPECTION" => $id,
                    "file_name" => $upload_data['file_name'],
                    "file_orig_name" => $upload_data['orig_name'],
                    "file_path" => $upload_data['full_path']
                );

                $this->load->library('image_lib');

                $resize_conf = array(
                    'source_image' => $upload_data['full_path'],
                    'new_image' => $upload_data['file_path'] . '\thumbs\thumb_' . $upload_data['file_name'],
                    'width' => 200,
                    'height' => 200
                );

                //use first config
                $this->image_lib->initialize($resize_conf);
                //run resize
                if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
                    echo "Failed." . $this->image_lib->display_errors();
                }
                //clear
                $this->image_lib->clear();

                //initialize second config
                $this->image_lib->initialize($resize_conf);
                //run resize
                if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
                    echo "Failed." . $this->image_lib->display_errors();
                }
                //clear
                $this->image_lib->clear();
                //push all informatin to array for insert batch
                array_push($upload_array, $new_upload);
            }
        }
        //Insert batch codeingter
        $this->m_surveyor->save_files_info($upload_array);
        if ($errors > 0) {
            echo $errors . "File(s) cannot be uploaded";
        }
    } elseif ($this->input->post('file_to_remove')) {
        $file_to_remove = $this->input->post('file_to_remove');
        unlink("./assets/uploads/" . $file_to_remove);
    } else {
        $this->listFiles();
    }
}
```

I have case like this :
 1. User choose a or lot of file images on first chance, e-g 2 files image.
 2. After loaded, user choose a file again
 3. But, the image that was successfully upload just one last file chosen. The two files in not uploaded ?

In my controller, I use insert batch. So i must to save all information into database in array(array(),array());

Is it possible to upload those file like triggered ? So, if user choose two files and then choose again another file, so on so on, all the choosed file will be uploaded.